# Sum of representation categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

Consider a superalgebra $A$ and its representation category $\text{Rep }A$. So the objects are assumed to be super-vector spaces and the action should be compatible with the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading.

Now, further assume that there is a decomposition of $A$ into ideals $$A=A_0\oplus A_1.$$

What does in this context $$\text{Rep }A=\text{Rep }A_0\oplus\text{Rep }A_1$$ mean?

So I could imagine that objects are of the form $U\oplus V$, where $U\in\text{Rep }A_0, V\in\text{Rep }A_1$. But what are the morphisms?

Comment: This notation does not seem to be sensible given that $A_1$ is not a subalgebra of $A$.

Comment: It is an ideal, so in particular a subalgebra, isn't it?

Comment: It's not an ideal. If $a,b\in A_1$ then $ab\in A_0$.

Comment: Oh that is maybe confusion: The decomposition into $A_i$ is NOT the decomposition as a superalgebra. It is another one.

Comment: Then perhaps you should use different notation.

Answer (score 2):

This statement says that any $V\in \operatorname{Rep}A$ decomposes as $V=V_0\oplus V_1$ with $V_i\in \operatorname{Rep} A_i$ **and** every morphism $f\in \mathrm{Hom}_A(V,W)$ decomposes as $f=f_1+f_2$ where $f_i\in\mathrm{Hom}_{A_i}(V_i,W_i)$.

The fact that $A$ is a superalgebra is entirely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: But is this true? Does every $f$ really decomposes as $f=f_1+f_2$? What, for instance, if $f$ is parity odd?

Comment: It is not true in general. The statement that $\operatorname{Rep}A=\operatorname{Rep}A_0\oplus\operatorname{Rep}A_1$ **asserts** that this is true. Also, you are mixing the (irrelevant to the question) $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ grading with the direct sum decomposition. This is why I complained about your notation in my comment above.

Comment: It is always true, that $V$ decomposes like above but not that $f$ decomposes, right? Under what assumptions the statement becomes true?

Comment: @user372565 Under the assumptions given in your question... If $A$ splits as a direct sum of two ideals, then every morphism splits as a sum of two morphisms. Just try to write down the proof!

Comment: That means it is true, that if $A$ splits as a direct sum of two ideals, every $A$ linear map $f:U\oplus V\to W\oplus X$ splits as $f=f_1+f_2$ with $f_1:U\to W$ and $f_2:V\to X$? Why there can't be a part like $U\to X$?